# Random numbers and the multicore package

Tags: r, random-generation, parallel-computing, multicore

When programming in R, I've used the [multicore](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/multicore/multicore.html) package a few times. However, I've never seen a statement about how it handles it's random numbers. When I use openMP with C, I'm careful to use a proper parallel RNG, but with R I've assume that something sensible happens. Can anyone confirm that something sensible does happen?

**Example**

From the documentation, we have

```
x <- foreach(icount(1000), .combine = "+") %do% rnorm(4)
```

How are the `rnorm``s generated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure how the `foreach` works (from the doMC package, I guess), but in multicore if you did something like `mclapply` the `mc.set.seed` parameter defaults to `TRUE` which gives each process a different seed (e.g. `mclapply(1:1000, rnorm)`).  I assume your code is translated into something similar, i.e. it boils down to calls to `parallel` which has the same convention.

But also see page 16 of the [slides](http://www.stat.umn.edu/~charlie/parallel/) by Charlie Geyer, which recommends the [rlecuyer](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlecuyer/index.html) package for parallel independent streams with theoretical guarantees.  Geyer's page also has sample code in R for the different setups.

Answer (score 7):

You might want to look at page 5 of this [document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multicore/multicore.pdf) and of this [document](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doMC/vignettes/gettingstartedMC.pdf). By default, under R, each core sets is own seed (i seem to recall using high precision time).

NB: if you use foreach() from Revolution-computing under windows then i suspect something sensible will **not** happen. Windows is not POSIX compliant, and this should pose problems when each core needs a different high prec. starting time to set it's seed (unfortunately i don't have windows handy so i can't check this empirically).