# RNG, R, mclapply and cluster of computers

Tags: r, random-generation, parallel-computing, multicore

I'm running a simulation on R and a cluster of computers and have the following problem. On each of X computers I run:

```
fxT2 <- function(i) runif(10)
nessay <- 100
c(mclapply(1:nessay, fxT2), recursive=TRUE)
```

There are 32 computers, each with 16 cores. However, around 2% of the random numbers are identical. What strategies would you adopt to avoid this?

I've been able to avoid this problem for fxT2 by setting a latency (i.e. delaying by a sec the time at which each job is send to each of the X computers). But it's seems very ad-hoc to fxt2.

The problem is that in reality fxT2 is a long task involving pseudo random numbers. At the end of the process, I expect to get X*nessay reproduction of the same statistical experiment, **not** nessay reproductions. How to make sure that this is indeed the case and is there a way to check this?.

Comment: Good question. Have a look at this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3532/random-numbers-and-the-multicore-package) on random numbers and the multicore package

Comment: @CSgillepsie:> thanks for the pointer, but i'm not sure it's the same problem: the way i understand the question you pointed to, all the processes are spawned by mclapply. Here it's a bit different: on each of the machines, all the processes are spawned by mclapply, but this is not the case *across* machines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [snow](http://cran.r-project.org/package=snow) has explicit support to initialise the given number of RNG streams in a cluster computation.

It can employ one of two RNG implementations:

- [rsprng](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rsprng) and
- [rlecuyer](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rlecuyer)

Otherwise you have to do the coordination by hand.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a RNG specifically designed for parallel computing.  See the "Parallel computing: Random numbers" section of the [High Performance Computing Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

Comment: You also need to coordinate between the RNG streams. Snow does that, multicore may now.